# Laravel Property of non-object error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have met a small hitch in my attempt at understanding laravel and need some help.

I have an "Appointments" model, controller and various views.

Model:

```
class Appointment extends Eloquent {

     protected $primaryKey = 'appointment_ID';
     protected $fillable = array('puser_ID', 'apt_date', 'apt_time', 'purpose');
     public $timestamps = false;


}
```

Controller:

```
class AppointmentsController extends BaseController{

    public $restful = true;

    public function getIndex(){
        return View::make('appointments.index')
        ->with('title','Docket: Appointments & Scheduling')
        ->with('appointments', Appointment::OrderBy('apt_time')->get());
    }

    public function getView($appointment_ID){
        return View::make('appointments.view')
        ->with('title', 'Appointment View')
        ->with('appointment', Appointment::find($appointment_ID));

    }
    public function getNew(){
        return View::make('appointments.index')
        ->with('title', 'Add A New Appointment');
    }
}
```

"Add New Appointment" view code:

```
extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')
    <h1>Add A New Appointment</h1>

    {{ Form::open(array('url'=>'appointments/create', 'method'=>'post')) }}

<p>
    {{Form::label('puserID', 'User ID')}}<br/>
    {{Form::text('puser_ID'}}
</p>

<p>
    {{Form::label('aptDate', 'Appointment Date')}}<br/>
    {{Form::text('apt_date')}}
</p>        

<p>
    {{Form::label('aptTime', 'Contact Number 1')}}<br/>
    {{Form::text('aptTime'}}
</p>

<p> 
    {{Form::label('purpose', 'Purpose of Visit')}}<br/>
    {{Form::text('purpose'}}
</p>    

<p> {{Form::submit('Add Appointment')}}</p>

{{ Form::close() }}

@endsection
```

and my Routes.php file (UPDATED):

```
Route::get('appointments',array('as'=>'appointments','uses'=>'AppointmentsController@getIndex'));

Route::get('appointments/{appointment_ID}',array('as'=>'appointment','uses'=>'AppointmentsController@getView'));

Route::get('appointments/new',array('as'=>'newAppointment','uses'=>'AppointmentsController@getNew')    );
```

I am trying to go from the "Index" view (listing all appointments) to the "Add New Appointment" view using a button in the index view:

```
<p>{{ HTML::linkRoute('newAppointment', 'New Appointment') }}</p>
```

but the code is throwing the "Trying to get property of non-object" Error when I press the "New Appointment" button from the index view.

Please help.

default/layout View as requested:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>{{$title}}</title>
</head>
<body>
    @if(Session::has('message'))
        <p style="color: green;">{{ Session::get('message') }}</p>
    @endif

    @yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

Error Message:

```
ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object
open: /Library/WebServer/Documents/laravel-master/app/storage/views/5258152a378521b65c6fd9801aedd9fd
<?php $__env->startSection('content'); ?>

    <h1><?php echo e($appointment->puser_ID); ?></h1>
    <p><small><?php echo e($appointment->apt_date); ?></small></p>
    <p><small><?php echo e($appointment->apt_time); ?></small></p>
    <p><small><?php echo e($appointment->purpose); ?></small></p>
```

Comment: In which line/file is the error thrown?

Comment: The log doesn't say explicitly but in the code that is displayed, it looks to be the "appointment.view" code. This code just outputs 4 fields like <?php echo $appointment -> puser_ID ?>... "../app/storage/views/5258152a.....fd:3"

Comment: Show us the dull error message please. Alternatively, do you have error logs available (chances are yes) - what's your dev server environment

Comment: I have appended it to what is above.

Comment: The dev server environment is MAMP using php 5.4.4

Answer (score 0):

the view in getNew(), should not be a diferent view the index? eg: `View::make('appointments.new')` instance of `View::make('appointments.index')`

```
public function getNew(){
    return View::make('appointments.new')
    ->with('title', 'Add A New Appointment');
}
```

### EDIT

you have sintax errors in `Form::text()`. you have to close the parentheses in all you `Form::text()`. if this not resolve, post your `layout/default` view.

### EDIT 2

should not be

```
Route::get('appointments/new',array('as'=>'newAppointment','uses'=>'AppointmentsController@getNew')    );
```

instance of:

```
Route::get('appointments/new',array('as'=>'newAppointment','uses'=>'UsersController@getNew')    );
```

?

Comment: Yes, It should have been 'appointments.new'. I changed it for testing. That doesn't solve the problem though.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've made the changes but it doesn't solve the problem.
layout/default view:<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>{{$title}}</title>
</head>
<body>
 @if(Session::has('message'))
  <p style="color: green;">{{ Session::get('message') }}</p>
 @endif

 @yield('content')
</body>
</html>

Comment: The code seems to be referencing an earlier model I had created. I have another model, controller and set of views and am trying to do a different model with similar functions. Why is it referencing the older model?

Comment: Just did. Problem persists.

Comment: I have it as appointmentsController@getNew in the code I have here. The problem still exists.
I made some changes to try and isolate the problem. the UsersController@getNew was a remnant of the changes that I had made. I reverted everything.

Comment: if you use the 'UsersController@getNew' method, put this methos here, and update your code in question.

Answer (score 0):

Migration : Post

```
<?php
```

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration {

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('read_more');
        $table->string('content');
        $table->unsignedInteger('comment_count');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->engine = 'MyISAM';
    });
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE posts ADD FULLTEXT search(title, content)');
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
   Schema::table('posts', function(Blueprint $table){
       $table->dropIndex('search');
       $table->drop();
   });
}
```

}
Controller :

```
public function show($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id)->toArray();
    return View::make('detail', compact('post'));
}
```

Display : detail.blade.php

```
@extends("layouts.master")

@section('content')
{{$post['id']}}
{{$post['title']}}
@stop
```

Answer (score 0):

Value return is object . You can use toArray() return object to array() . when you fetch value to display elements with blade template like {{$post['id']}}